# Move items dynamically up/down

Tags: java, swing

I am having a pane and add items to the pane. At the moment I have implemented the delete functionality into my program, however I would like to also shift elements around by moving them upwards or downwards. However, I am struggeling with the algorithm. Here is a working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class minimumExample extends JFrame {

    private JButton addItem;

    private JComboBox itemBox;

    private String[] itemSelect = { "test1", "test2" };

    private JPanel addUpperPane;

    private JPanel addLowerPane;

    private List<CheckItem> displayedItems = new ArrayList<CheckItem>();

    private JButton upButton;

    private JButton downButton;

    private JButton deleteButton;

    public void createControlPane() {

        addUpperPane = new JPanel();
        addLowerPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        addItem = new JButton("Add item");
        upButton = new JButton("Up");
        downButton = new JButton("Down");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");

        itemBox = new JComboBox(itemSelect);

        addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test1")) {
                    ButtonComp butt = new ButtonComp();
                    butt.init();
                    displayedItems.add(butt);
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test2")) {
                    LabelComp label = new LabelComp();
                    label.label();
                    displayedItems.add(label);
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < displayedItems.size(); i++) {
                    addLowerPane.add(displayedItems.get(i).getComponent());
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });


        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                System.out.println("delete Item");

                Iterator<CheckItem> it = displayedItems.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    CheckItem next = it.next();
                    if (next.isSelected()) {
                        addLowerPane.remove(next.getComponent());
                        it.remove();
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                validate();
                repaint();

            }
        });

        upButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                System.out.println("move item up");

                //how to move items up

                validate();
                repaint();

            }
        });

        addUpperPane.add(itemBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
        addUpperPane.add(addItem, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JLabel(" | "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(upButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(downButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(deleteButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL));

        //put everything together

        add(addUpperPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(addLowerPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        repaint();

    }

    private void makeLayout() {

        setTitle("Test App");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));

        createControlPane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * starts the GUI
     */
    public void start() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeLayout();   
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        minimumExample ex = new minimumExample();
        ex.start();
    }

    public abstract class CheckItem {

        protected JCheckBox check;

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return check.isSelected();
        }

        public abstract Component getComponent();

    }

    public class ButtonComp extends CheckItem {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        public void init() {
            JButton button = new JButton("Test1");
            check = new JCheckBox();
            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(check);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponent() {
            return panel;
        }
    }

    public class LabelComp extends CheckItem {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        public void label() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Test2");
            check = new JCheckBox();
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(check);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponent() {
            return panel;
        }
    }
}
```

I researched that a possible solution might be to use `Collections.swap`. Any recommendations on how to implement this in swing, I am really stuck...

I appreciate your answer!
Any recommendations how t

Comment: Ugh, those inheritances make little sense. What does `getComponent` mean in CheckItem? And then a subclass has a panel that contains the checkbox of the parent class? You don't need to make classes but if you want the base class has to contain or extend JPanel. This way "getComponent" makes sense. It means to retrieve the component that the subclass will put in this base panel. Also, each time you add items, you re-add the old ones, which happens to work because a component can only have a single parent, but I don't know If this way is "legal". Adding without removing first.

Comment: And what you need to do is to swap two elements in the `displayedItems` list and then (remove and) re-add these components to the `addLowerPane`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need is a way to get a reference to the component you wish to move up or down.  You might need to keep a reference to the currently selected component that gets updated each time you change the selection that you can grab each time for move up/down.

After that, I feel you're almost there.

Go through your displayedItems and find the position of this component in the list.  If you're moving it up (and there is a component above it), use your Collections.swap to switch it's position with the component before it.

Then you're going to remove all the components from addLowerPane and run this section of code again.  (Since you reuse it, you might want to create it's own method)

```
for (int i = 0; i < displayedItems.size(); i++) {
    addLowerPane.add(displayedItems.get(i).getComponent());
    validate();
    repaint();
}
```